# Resize button's text to go in next line

Tags: c#

I need when the text in my button is too long to show the second word in new line.
Or if its only one word with very big length to separate my word in two pieces. One piece in Up line and one piece in a new line.

I'm trying something like this but i cant it resizes also my buttton.I dont want to resize my button.

```
button.AutoSize = true;
```

Just check Images Below
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNUGD.jpg)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXB9Q.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you make the button taller?

Comment: It loos the same. I dont get any difference

Comment: If it is tall enough the text will wrap.  If you want your text to 'go in next line" you have to give it room for those lines (or shrink the font).  `I dont want to resize my button` you cant have it both ways

Comment: @Dim, post some images of how you think it should look. Also, is this WinForm or WPF?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(glassButton1.Text.Length>5)
            {
                int sum = glassButton1.Text.Length - 5;
                string line1 = glassButton1.Text.Substring(0, 5);
                string line2 = glassButton1.Text.Substring(glassButton1.Text.Length - sum);
                glassButton1.Text = line1 + Environment.NewLine + line2;
            }
        }

        private void glassButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lines = glassButton1.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string address = lines[0];
            string address2 = lines[1];
            MessageBox.Show(address+address2);
        }
```

Comment: The problem is i'm using custom button so it doesnt have the option to auto wrap my text,  i must do it manually